# Add attributes to an object for different indexes using filter

Tags: javascript, filter

I am a beginner with `javascript`. I'd like to squeeze this piece of code using `filter`. I want to create an object and for some indexes add one attribute and for another indexes assign different attribute.

```
var nodeAttribute=new Object();
var minorityNodes=[ 22, 1, 2, 10, 14, 23, 25, 4, 15 ];
var N=30;
for (var i=0; i<N; i++){
    if (minorityNodes.indexOf(i) >= 0){
        nodeAttribute[i]='minority';
    }else{
        nodeAttribute[i]='majority';
    }
}
```

How should it be done?

**Update**

```
nodeAttribute
{ '0': 'majority',
  '1': 'minority',
  '2': 'minority',
  '3': 'majority',
  '4': 'minority',
  '5': 'majority',
  '6': 'majority',
  '7': 'majority',
  '8': 'majority',
  '9': 'majority',
  '10': 'minority',
  '11': 'majority',
  '12': 'majority',
  '13': 'majority',
  '14': 'minority',
  '15': 'minority',
  '16': 'majority',
  '17': 'majority',
  '18': 'majority',
  '19': 'majority',
  '20': 'majority',
  '21': 'majority',
  '22': 'minority',
  '23': 'minority',
  '24': 'majority',
  '25': 'minority',
  '26': 'majority',
  '27': 'majority',
  '28': 'majority',
  '29': 'majority' }
```

Comment: its not that clear .. how should the resulting array look?

Comment: @Y.Hewa I added an example result to the question.

Comment: This code works - why use `filter`?

Comment: this works. what excatly is your question?

Comment: @FrankModica because I would like to extend it to a large data set and save more time for the analysis.

Comment: But `filter` would return a subset of the dataset that meet certain criteria. That's not what you're doing in the example. Is that what you need to do?

Comment: @FrankModica yes I was trying to modify this piece of code based on example and the documentation but I could not figure it out how I can reduce time complexity of this for loop. I am wondering whether there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `filter` would help with this scenario (or with performance), since it iterates over a collection and returns a subset.

If you're targeting modern browsers you can use a set for quicker lookup (sorry if the syntax is incorrect, I'm on mobile):

```
var nodeAttribute={};
var minorityNodes=new Set([22, 1, 2, 10, 14, 23, 25, 4, 15 ]);
var N=30;
for (var i=0; i<N; i++){
    if (minorityNodes.has(i)) {
        nodeAttribute[i]='minority';
    }else{
        nodeAttribute[i]='majority';
    }
}
```

If you can't use a set, use an object:

```
var minorityNodes = {
    22: true,
    1: true,
    // etc
};
```

And check for existence:

```
if (minorityNodes[i]) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is almost similar to what I post as question. I would like to know whether it is possible to use `filter` function here?

Comment: This is quicker because of the Set / object lookup time. I'm not sure why you want to use `filter`. It returns a subset of a collection - which collection do you need a subset of? Maybe I misunderstand.